# RNCamera QR code works on Android, not on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native

Having a issue with RNCamera. It works just fine reading the QR code in Android, but the QR onBarCodeRead does not get triggered in IOS.
Has anybody had any experience with this?

Implementation:

```
<RNCamera
                    type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back
                    flashMode={this.state.flash}
                    permissionDialogTitle={''}
                    permissionDialogMessage={''}
                    barCodeTypes={[RNCamera.Constants.BarCodeType.qr]}
                    style={FlexUtils.Flex1}
                    onBarCodeRead={this.onBarCodeRead}
                />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known problem](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/1706) , please check the [issues](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues) of the respective module before posting

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question since that issue is closed [without a real resolution](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/1706#issuecomment-532531553). Also, asking questions on SO even with existing open GH issues is completely valid way to get help (especially when the open issue is closed without being resolved).